# Handsontable header with weekly date format

Tags: date, handsontable

I want to implement [handsontable](https://handsontable.com/?_ga=1.228582367.392601433.1479295884) like header contains weekly date format, for more check below image [image]

Header start with current date to next seven days and one button for next and previous date scrolling. I tried following code with [help](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0-beta1/demo-date.html) of this

```
 {
    type: 'date',
    dateFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY',
    correctFormat: true,
    defaultDate: '01/01/1900'
  }
```

but it shows date picker in as cell values not column header. Is any one know how to show current week start from Monday in column header using handsontable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some search and with help of java script I came with my solution for more check this

```
function loadTable(weekDays) {
var example2 = document.getElementById('example2');
var hot2 = new Handsontable(example2, {
data: Handsontable.helper.createSpreadsheetData(3, 7),
colHeaders: weekDays
});

function bindDumpButton() {
  if (typeof Handsontable === "undefined") {
    return;
  }

  Handsontable.Dom.addEvent(document.body, 'click', function (e) {

    var element = e.target || e.srcElement;

    if (element.nodeName == "BUTTON" && element.name == 'dump') {
      var name = element.getAttribute('data-dump');
      var instance = element.getAttribute('data-instance');
      var hot = window[instance];
      console.log('data of ' + name, hot.getData());
    }
  });
}
bindDumpButton();
}
```

for more check this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yogesh_0586/0yxak4xj/12/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=0yxak4xj)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use this method because columns is only used for body table.

You can use afterGetColHeader ([doc](http://docs.handsontable.com/0.29.0/Hooks.html#event:afterGetColHeader)) :

```
afterGetColHeader(col, TH) {

}
```

And insert date picker in the TH element.